# Unable to find an entry point named 'aruco_Dictionary_delete' in shared library 'OpenCvSharpExtern'

Tags: c#, opencv, ubuntu-18.04

Recently I have upgraded the NuGets of OpenCvSharp to their latest version. However, when using OpenCvSharp.Aruco in Ubuntu 18.04 (having, of course, the corresponding runtime NuGet installed) it arises this error:

> Unhandled Exception:Unable to find an entry point named 'aruco_Dictionary_delete' in shared library 'OpenCvSharpExtern'.
> |ERROR| NativeMethods.aruco_Dictionary_delete => NativeMethods.aruco_Dictionary_delete => Program.CurrentDomain_UnhandledException - Line: 105 Unable to find an entry point named 'aruco_Dictionary_delete' in shared library 'OpenCvSharpExtern'. System.EntryPointNotFoundException    at OpenCvSharp.Internal.NativeMethods.aruco_Dictionary_delete(IntPtr ptr)
> at OpenCvSharp.Aruco.Dictionary.DisposeUnmanaged()
> at OpenCvSharp.DisposableObject.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
> at OpenCvSharp.DisposableObject.Finalize() ERROR Unhandled Exception:Unable to find an entry point named 'aruco_Dictionary_delete' in shared library 'OpenCvSharpExtern'

Do you know if there is something I can do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was installing the last OpenCV and OpenCvSharp from source code in github, and then copy the library to the C# solution.

Comment: For me this error seemed to perhaps be caused by a mismatch between the OpenCvSharp and OpenCvSharp.runtime versions. I downgraded back to 4.6 (since there's no newer Ubuntu 22.04 build available) and it seems to work without issues again.